# How to fix JUnit test case error in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, junit

I have freshly created a Kotlin project in IntelliJ Community Edition and while creating a sample unit test using JUnit 4, I'm getting the following error.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
}

group 'main.kotlin.com'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

#### Error:

```
Cannot access class 'java.lang.Class'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

[error-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcZu7.jpg) |
[project-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbRsw.jpg) |
[modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg4FY.jpg) 
P.S.If I create a Java project and try to create a sample unit test then its successfully creating a test without any error.

#### Update:

If I change the Project SDK from JDK-1.8 to JDK-9 then it's working completely fine

Comment: Do you have project JDK configured? Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html.

Comment: I have project JDK configured. Still, if I have done that wrong, I have updated the question and added the screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/Ku7xz5i.png) the problem. Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

right click on module and check module settings . JVM settings could be wrong.
[Check if](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6ujc.png)

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question and added the screenshots. Please have a look.